# How to ransfer(move) AWS EC2 instance from A account to b account but IP unchanged?

Tags: amazon-ec2

I have a instance in AWS EC2 A account,

I want to move it From AWS EC2 A account to AWS EC2 B account,

but the instance IP can not be changed，how do i do it?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's not possible.

Instances cannot be moved across account boundaries, they can only be clones.

Elastic IPs also cannot be moved.

Your service should use DNS names and not be dependent on a fixed IP address.